# Get latest from tfs server using CLI

Tags: tfs, batch-file, command-line-interface

Im working on this command line which should allow me to get latest version from my team foundation server. I just made a lot of google look up and everytime I got stuck.

Here is what I got and what I want.

I want to get latest version from a directory ("$/projects/name") recursive and place it in a local folder ("D:\destination")

This is where I got stuck trying to do the call:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" get "$/projects/name" /force /recursive "D:\destination" /server:tfs.server.net

this would make sense to me, but somehow it doesn't work.

I use the new tfs 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team Foundation Server uses *workspace mappings* to configure where server paths should be downloaded on to the local filesystem.  This allows for very complex source control configuration scenarios, but it also means that you'll need to do a few more steps before downloading your code:  namely, [creating a workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [setting the workspace mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before finally [performing the get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

To do this with the TFS command-line client:

```
tf workspace /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /new /noprompt WORKSPACE_NAME
tf workfold /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /map $/Server/Path C:\Local\Path
tf get C:\Local\Path
```